# Where is the .NET Core reference documentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I am porting my .NET 4.0 library to a UWP one however the Types are similar but different, for example the members available on a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` are significantly different, e.g. `Available, SetSocketOption(), IPProtectionLevel, Blocking` are all missing from the UWP one.

When I press F1 on the my UWP `Socket` in VS2015 I am taken to the .NET 4.6 MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.Sockets.Socket);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true, which has all those members.

How do I get to the UWP documentation about the Type I am using?

I can see .NETCore is the query string but here is no indication on that MSDN page about which members are available in UWP, it is just the .NET desktop page.

Please don't tell me there is no UWP reference documentation :S

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core API reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/index

Unfortunately it's nowhere near as complete as what we've come to expect from MSDN.

Answer (score -1):

Good news is its here: http://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bcl/api-ref.html

Bad news is its not written yet..

Comment: Bad news is that link is broken.